# What db/fileformat to use for append-only, LIFO, mostly-read operations from python script?

Tags: python, database, append

I'm going to receive a daily list of product prices and I need to:

- store it (single process, once every night, doesn't matter if it takes hours, reads stopped, all data is ready to be written in a single batch)
- quickly read the latest price for a given product (multithreaded web app, must be fast)
- sometimes read the whole price history for a given product (cron job script to draw graphs, doesn't matter if it is slow)
- keep the whole history for years (never forget anything)
- bonus points if the nightly (write) job is a simple python script not depending on external services
- just to be clear: there are no writes other than the nightly job, and the latter runs in a single process and can run with reads disabled from the actual db/file

I'm looking for recommendations for the most efficient way to achieve that, programming language is [Python-2.7](http://www.python.org/), with 3.x being available if needed.

I was thinking about storing on [possibly multiple] file[s] the actual data with whole history, and maybe updating a [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.5.html) db with only the latest prices for every item (for the web app to consume). The file could be [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) (stable, proven, and "fast enough" for us. bonus: can be used via [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) which we love) or some other file format ([CDB](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-cdb) or the like) if there are enough reasons, and I can manage some sort of "rotation" (i.e., one file per year) if that's needed to achieve fast reads of the latest data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with sqlite, since it's included directly with python.
Slap on SQLAlchemy and it should be easy enough to swap out the underlying DB as needed.

Test with that and if it's not enough move to a more powerful db.  (I prefer postgres).